# How to change JLabel variable name at run time?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have more than 100 `JLabel` components in my `JFrame` and I have named them like `m1,m2,m3....` and I want to change text of each of them without doing it manually.

So I want to set name of each label at run time and change its text, which I am retrieving from a database.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
JLabel j = new JLabel(); 

for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++)
{   
    j.setName("m"+i);
    j.setText(""+i);
}
```

Comment: *"I have more than 100 JLabel components .. I want to set name of each label at run time and change its text, which I am retrieving from a database."*  This sounds like the data should be presented in a single `JList` or `JTable` component of DB values, rather than in separate `JLabel` components...

Answer (score 3):

you can create a jlabel array .then you can access it as `m[x]` 
example

```
JLabel m[] = new JLabel[100]; 

//initialize jlabel array before you add  like m[i]=new JLabel();

for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
     m[i].setText(""+i);     
}
```

the problem you are facing is even you have named labels as `m1,m2` you can't call by dynamically making it's name.

```
m+"i".setText(); // impossible
```